# MongoDB - query in denormalized model

Tags: mongodb

I have to show the advantages to use normalized model(in this case), with two collections in MongoDB: the first for coaches and the second for teams.
So, I use a denormalized model to show the differences.
For example, if I want to update the palmarès of Barcellona(from 23 Liga to 24 Liga), with denormalized model, I have to find all coaches that coached Barcellona and then I have to update the palmarès inside each coach. Clearly it's too expensive. I want to do this example.

I have this denormalized model of soccer coaches and teams they have coached.
Here is an example:

```
     "_id" : "LEMG_1970",
  "name" : "Luis",
  "surname" : "Enrique Martinez Garcia",
  "age" : 45,
  "date_Of_birth" : {
          "day" : 8,
          "month" : 5,
          "year" : 1970
  },
  "place_Of_birth" : "Gijòn",
  "nationality" : "Spanish",
  "preferred_formation" : "4-3-3 off",
  "coached_Team" : [
          {


"_id" : "Bar.43",
   "official_name" : "Futbol Club Barcelona"
   "common_name" : "Barcellona",
   "country" : "Spain",
   "started_by" : {
           "day" : 28,
           "month" : 11,
           "year" : 1899
   },
   "championship" : "La Liga",
   "stadium" : {
           "name" : "Camp Nou",
           "capacity" : 99354
   },
   "palmarès" : {
           "La Liga" : 23,
           "Copa del Rey" : 27,
           "Supercopa de Espana" : 11,
           "UEFA Champions League" : 4,
           "UEFA Cup Winners Cup" : 4,
           "UEFA Super Cup" : 4,
           "FIFA Club World cup" : 2
   },
   "average age" : 26.9,
   "squad value(in mln)" : 591.5,
   "foreigners" : 13,
   "uniform" : [
           "blue",
           "dark red"
   ],
                  "in_charge" : {
                          "from" : {
                                  "day" : 1,
                                  "month" : 7,
                                  "year" : 2014
                          }
                  },
                  "matches" : 59
          },
          {

          {
         "_id" : "Rom.01",
   "official_name" : "Associazione Sportiva Roma SpA",
   "common_name" : "Roma",
   "country" : "Italy",
   "started_by" : {
           "day" : 22,
           "month" : 6,
           "year" : 1927
   },
   "championship" : "Serie A",
   "stadium" : {
           "name" : "Olimpico di Roma",
           "capacity" : 73261
   },
   "palmarès" : {
           "Serie A" : 3,
           "Coppa Italia" : 9,
           "Supercoppa Italiana" : 2,
           "Serie B" : 1
   },
   "average age" : 28.3,
   "squad value(in mln)" : 253.7,
   "foreigners" : 22,
   "uniform" : [
           "red",
           "yellow"
   ],
                  "in_charge" : {
                          "from" : {
                                  "day" : 7,
                                  "month" : 6,
                                  "year" : 2011
                          },
                          "to" : {
                                  "day" : 10,
                                  "month" : 5,
                                  "year" : 2012
                          }
                  },
                  "matches" : 41
          }
  ]
```

As you can see information about teams are into coach document. Now, I want to update the palmarès of Barcellona. I tried this query, but I got an error:

```
 db.coach.update({_id:"LEMG_1970"}, {$set:{"coached_Team.palmarès.La Liga":24}})
```

This is the advice:

```
"code" : 16837,
            "errmsg" : "cannot use the part (coached_Team of coached_Team.palmar├¿s.La Liga) to traverse the element
```

What can I do to update the palmarès with denormalized model?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use the **[`$` positional operator](http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/reference/operator/update/positional/)** in your update, this identifies an element in an array to update without explicitly specifying the position of the element in the array. Since the positional **[`$`](http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/reference/operator/update/positional/)** operator acts as a placeholder for the first element that matches the query document, the the array field must appear as part of the query document hence you need the `coached_Team` array field in your query:

```
var query = {
        "_id" : "LEMG_1970",
        "coached_Team._id" : "Bar.43"
    },
    update = {
        "$set": {
            "coached_Team.$.palmarès.La Liga": 24
        }
    };

db.coach.update(query, update);
```